# How can I access link by selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

**Problem** : can not click link which is using javascript by selenium.

**tried** : 1.
`element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(a {href: "javascript:void(0)"}`
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

2. `element = driver.execute_script("javascript_:void(0)")` Nothing happened.

**element**
`<a href="javascript_:void(0)" onclick="changeVis('dnskvmenu', 'dnskvtree')">「戒蘊篇」</a>`

How can I access link by selenium?
How can I click that link?
I have found similar problem but I can not understand answer.
Does anyone know the reason of this problem? Or are there other ways to access the link?

[Access link by url which is javascript using selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638024/access-link-by-url-which-is-javascript-using-selenium)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the element you want with nth-child, based on the div that the link is located in.

#sidebarElement a:nth-child(1)

Comment: Is this what you mean? ```a = 'body > table:nth-child(5) > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > div > a'
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(a).click()```

Comment: No. You're trying to get the first link of your sidebar, so get the sidebar id and replace the #sidebarElement with the id of your sidebar, and use nth-child to get the first a of this div. Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child